# Why this code is printing string rather than printing address?

Tags: c++

Here in this code, `cout<<q<<endl;` is returning string "mani"?. q contain the address of first character 'm' so it should print address not string.please explain.

```
int main(){
    char *q;
    char b[5]={'m','a','n','i'};
    q=&b[0];
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<q<<endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::cout` has a special overload for `const char*`, which outputs the memory as an array of `char`s starting at the pointer passed up to the next NUL terminator (it's your job to make sure that the appropriate memory is available for that).

If you want to switch off this behaviour and output the pointer address then use a cast:

```
std::cout << (const void*)b << endl;
```

Comment: I suppose a static cast will be more C++ like.

Comment: @Stargateur: I prefer my way as it sorts out any `const_cast` too. Every C++ programmer ought to know how the C-style cast behaves in C++.

Comment: IIRC a static cast may be used to add a const qualifier. That's deemed "safe", supposedly. But I wouldn't wager a beer on it.